# I keep leaving a chat room and it keeps appearing under "other rooms you're in"

Tags: bug, chat

I visited another chat room today and now I can't leave it.

I keep clicking the *leave that room* button from another room I'm in, and it disappears until someone posts a new message. The only other tab I have with a chat room is on the MSE server.

> [image: screenshot of button to leave the room]

Did something break?

Comment: This might be worthy of meta SE?

Comment: Anything on-topic at Meta.SE is on-topic here. A moderator can/will migrate it if they feel it is necessary. Otherwise, you can flag it for migration. There's no reason to have this extended discussion about which site it belongs on in the comments. It is rather too late now, it's already been posted.

Comment: The 'leave' button also does not work. I always need to click the button 'all' to get out chat.

Comment: @AndreSilva Even the *all* link doesn't seem to work. Upon rejoining the room in the screenshot, the other room will also appear again.

Comment: Hmmm; cannot repro; are you sure you haven't left chat open in another browser window (perhaps on a different machine) ? We do try to propagate leave events to all your browsers, but sometimes things get complicated...

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm quite sure I shut down my machines at home this morning. No other browsers open on this machine. The issue also only appeared after I initially joined the JavaScript room about an hour ago. [This user](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2337861#2337861) managed to reproduce it. I'm going home now for the weekend, I'll see if I also have the issue at home or if it's still there on Monday.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm home now, my machines were off but I'm having the same issue here. Is it possible for you to kill all my sessions? I'm using SE's OpenID.

Comment: The issue seems to have resolved itself over the weekend.

Comment: @MarcGravell in case you forgot about this, should this be closed as no longer reproducible, or should it stay open?

Comment: entirely up to you; I didn't manage to find out what was happening